# Can't find .htaccess loop error "Too many redirects"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I can't figure out why when trying to load a webpage for which I modified .htaccess file, the browser returns me the error "Too many redirects".

Can you help me to find inside the file where the mistake is?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([www\.]*domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([www\.]*domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/web [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is the first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([www\.]*domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is saying:

1. If the host is "www.domain.com" or "domain.com"
2. And the request isn't just "/"
3. Then redirect to the same host and request using the "https" scheme

So no matter what request you go to, you will always end up in a loop because of that rule.

Let's say, you go to `http://domain.com/`:

1. The host is "domain.com" and the URI is "/"
2. The second rule redirects the browser to `https://domain.com/web`
3. The browser loads the new URL
4. The host is "domain.com" and the URI is "/web"
5. The first rule redirects the browser to `https://domain.com/web`
6. Repeat starting from step **3**

Thus you have your redirect loop.

I have no idea what you're attempting to do with that rule, it really only does one thing and that one thing is to cause a permanent redirect loop.